# Is there any better method than collect to read an RDD in spark?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, bigdata

So, I want to read and RDD into an array. For that purpose, I could use the **collect** method. But that method is really annoying as in my case it keeps on giving kyro buffer overflow errors. If I set the kyro buffer size too much, it starts to have its own problems. On the other hand, I have noticed that if I just save the RDD into a file using the **saveAsTextFile** method, I get no errors. So, I was thinking, there must be some better method of reading an RDD into an array which isn't as problematic as the **collect** method.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask a question about the buffer overflow error.

Comment: The maximum size of Kyro Serializer buffer I can set is 1GB. So, does that mean, I can't collect anything more than 1GB?

Comment: Maybe switch to standard serialization?

Comment: @maasg: And how do you switch to standard serialization?

Comment: By setting `spark.serializer`. (See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html.) Kryo is not the default, so if you're using Kryo, you know how to set it :).

Comment: A more pertinent question would be a) Why you can not save the file and read it back? b) Why really you want >1G data in one driver?

Comment: @ayanguha Basically what I am doing is that I am using map to execute several instances of a program. I get the output of each instance in a string. Now the string size is almost 200MB. Then by using reduce, I want to combine those strings into one and write that string into a file at once. The total size of that combined string is around 4GB. And the RAM on the server where I am running this is 128 GB. Ideally, it should be no problem to do such a thing, but I am hitting the wall due to this spark serializer, which doesn't allow me to collect data more than 1GB.

Comment: Still, your idea of bringing everything to driver does not make sense to me. You can repartition the rdd to 1 partition and save to file as one. If you really want to do sequential way you may want to use forEachPartitions. Lookup the documentation and use yield to get values one at a time.

Answer (score 4):

No. `collect` is the only method for reading an RDD into an array.

`saveAsTextFile` never has to collect all the data to one machine, so it is not limited by the available memory on a single machine in the same way that `collect` is.

Comment: But why this collect method keeps throwing these buffer overflow errors. Moreover, I am an unable to set Kyro serializer maximum size to more than 1GB. So, it seems like its impossible to collect anything bigger than 1GB? Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have no idea what errors you are seeing. Also no idea why you cannot increase the setting (which setting?) beyond 1GB. (Have you also increased `spark.driver.maxResultSize`?) Anyway, one more thing you could try is using `RDD.toLocalIterator` instead of `collect`. Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: There's also a 2GB per-partition limit that you may be close to hitting. (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4885) In that case more partitions is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

toLocalIterator()

This method returns an iterator that contains all of the elements in this RDD.The iterator will consume as much memory as the largest partition in this RDD. Processes as RunJob to evaluate one single partition on each step.

```
>>> x = rdd.toLocalIterator()
>>> x
<generator object toLocalIterator at 0x283cf00>
```

then you can access the elements in rdd by

```
empty_array = []    
for each_element in x:
    empty_array.append(each_element)
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#toLocalIterator()