# Filtering One RDD based on another RDD using regex

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, rdd

I have two RDD's of the form:

```
data_wo_header: RDD[String], data_test_wo_header: RDD[String]
scala> data_wo_header.first
res2: String = 1,2,3.5,1112486027 
scala> data_test_wo_header.first
res2: String = 1,2
```

RDD2 is smaller than RDD 1. I am trying to filter RDD1 by removing the elements whose regEx matches with RDD2.

The 1,2 in the above example represent UserID,MovID. Since it's present in the test I want the new RDD such that it's removed from RDD1.

I have asked a similar [ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691419/combining-files) but it is requiring to do unnecessary split of RDD.
I am trying to do something of this sort but it's not working:

```
  def create_training(data_wo_header: RDD[String], data_test_wo_header: RDD[String]): List[String] = {

    var ratings_train = new ListBuffer[String]()
    data_wo_header.foreach(x => {
      data_test_wo_header.foreach(y => {
        if (x.indexOf(y) == 0) {
          ratings_train += x
        }
      })
    })
    val ratings_train_list = ratings_train.toList
    return ratings_train_list
  }
```

### How should I do a regex match and filter based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use broadcast variable to share state of rdd2 and then filter rdd1 based on broadcasted variable of rdd2. I replicate your code and this works for me

```
def create_training(data_wo_header: RDD[String], data_test_wo_header: RDD[String]): List[String] = {

   val rdd2array = sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(data_test_wo_header.collect())
   val training_set = data_wo_header.filter{
       case(x) => rdd2array.value.filter(y => x.matches(y)).length == 0
   }
   training_set.collect().toList
}
```

Also with scala and spark I recommend you if it is possible to avoid foreach and use more functional paradigm with map,flatMap and filter functions

Comment: I'm getting the error  `error: not found: value sparkSession` Do we need to pass the sparkSession value to the function we define?

Comment: When Is set `sparkSession=SparkSession.Builder()` and then define the function I get the error error: `method sparkContext in class Builder cannot be accessed in org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builde val rdd2array = sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(data_test_wo_header.collect())`

Comment: Okay got it what SparkSession is about

Comment: sorry I was using sparkSession fromy my main method, sparkSession is from spark 2.0 you initialize in a similar way like sparkContext before

Comment: it works for you after passed sparkSession? if yes can you mark it as anwered :)

Comment: It's running but since the dataset is large doing collect is making it take too much tiime. Can we somehow do away with Collect operation

Comment: you need to use collect to see the result

Comment: It's taking like a day to run(it's still running). Can there be a more efficient way. The same task using unix commands like grep and all should do it in seconds. It should be possible

Comment: Do you think if we can do away with `training_set.collect().toList` collect ? Can we use `training_set.toList` directly

Comment: There are no other way to collect results from RDD, you can probably achieve better results by saving results to file  using saveAsTextFile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333780/is-there-any-better-method-than-collect-to-read-an-rdd-in-spark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138042/discussion-between-stevesk-and-prateek-agrawal).